# How to increase the speedup of this Cuda code

Tags: c++, cuda

```
global void dummyKernel(Matrix Ad, Matrix Xd) {
    int[] tempData = new int[2];
    tempData[0] = threadIdx.x ;
    tempData[1] = blockIdx.x * blockDim;
    Xd.elements[tempData[1] + tempData[0]] = Xd.elements[tempData[1] + tempData[0]] * 5;
}
```

I have to increase the speedup of this code somehow

Comment: What is `Matrix`? Passing it by value looks very fishy. And a possible bottleneck if the compiler can't inline.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the new and the assignments and multiple additions:

```
int tmp = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
Xd.elements[tmp] *= 5;
```

Comment: @talonmies where do get the '.x' of blockDim?

Comment: The code in the question is invalid and wouldn't compile. `blockDim` is a  structure just like `threadIdx` and `blockIdx`. All automatic variables populated by the CUDA runtime